# How to deploy a contract in web3js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment, testrpc

I tested in testrpc, and already learned how to create and deploy contract by geth commands, but always failed in web3js script.
my very simple contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Test {
  string public projName;

  function Test()
  {
    projName = 'Test Proj';
  }

  function getProjName() view public returns(string)
  {
    return projName;
  }
}
```

And i complied this contract in [remix online complier](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.18+commit.9cf6e910.js)
And this is my webjs script below:

```
'use strict';
const Web3 = require("web3");
var IcoContractABI = {
  abi :[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getProjName","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"projName","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}],
  contractData : '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'
}

try {
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
console.log("web3 version: " + web3.version);

var ac = web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add('0x2722c1af21d9129f8c028b64d2a6f76b52e1ca7e4fa2beb293323f94c2b2601b');
console.log("address: " + ac.address);

var mycontract = new web3.eth.Contract(IcoContractABI.abi);

mycontract.deploy({
    data: IcoContractABI.contractData,
}).send({
    from: ac.address,
    gas: '47000000',
    gasPrice: '30000000000000'
}, function (error, transactionHash) {
    console.log("error= " + error.toString() + "; transactionHash=" + transactionHash);
})
    .on('error', function(error){
        console.log("error= " + error.toString());
    })
    .on('transactionHash', function(transactionHash){
        console.log("transactionHash= " + transactionHash.toString());
    })
    .on('receipt', function(receipt){
        console.log(receipt.contractAddress) // contains the new contract address
    })
    .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){

    })
    .then(function(newContractInstance){
        console.log(newContractInstance.options.address); // instance with the new contract address
    });

} catch (err) {
  console.log("error: " + err.toString());
  console.log(err.stack);
}
```

Then I run "node test.js", and always get the exception:

```
$ node test_deploy.js 
web3 version: 1.0.0-beta.24
address: 0x440a09de60d308109896179009E0270f1F65b38e
error= Error: Returned error: Error: invalid rlp: total length is larger than the data
at _decode (/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:15040:13)
at Object.exports.decode (/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:14943:17)
at Object.exports.defineProperties (/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:3138:18)
at new Transaction (/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:69871:13)
at new FakeTransaction (/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:16658:5)
at StateManager.queueRawTransaction (/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:83036:12)
at GethApiDouble.eth_sendRawTransaction (/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:82635:14)
at GethApiDouble.handleRequest (/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:82434:10)
at next (/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:52153:18)
at VmSubprovider.handleRequest (/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:59291:12); transactionHash=undefined
```

I have no idea what these exception messages mean and don't know how to fix it.

Any help will be very appreciated.

===================================

The problem above only exists in testrpc. I can deploy in private chain without error, so it seems that the testrpc is not so perfect to test the contract.
I will suggest to test in private chain if you want to test deploying contract in the web3js code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try the following solution that worked for me using Infura & Web3js.

```
let byteCode = {<YOUR CONTRACT'S BYTE-CODE GOES HERE>};
let contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abiChildContract);
let deploy = contractInstance.deploy({ data: '0x' + byteCode.object,
arguments: [tokenContractAddress, masterAdmin, masterAdmin]
}).encodeABI();

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(masterAdmin, 'pending').then((count) => {
let transactionObject = {
  data: deploy,
  from: senderAddress,
  nonce: count
};
web3.eth.estimateGas(transactionObject, function (err, estimate) {

  transactionObject.gas = estimate;
  web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transactionObject, privateKey, 
  function (error, signedTx) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      let tx = web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
      tx.on('transactionHash', function (transactionHash) {
  console.log(transactionHash); });
```

In the above code `let byteCode` stores your contract's byte-code (make sure that you copy it correctly!). The `senderAddress` in the `let transactionObject` is the address (i.e. public address) which is signing the contract deployment transaction with its `privateKey`.
At the end if all goes well, you get the `transactionHash` of the contract deployment transaction.
For more features/functionality with `contract.deploy` check out [this link](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id11).
Also, I strongly suggest using [Infura](https://blog.infura.io/getting-started-with-infura-28e41844cc89) as it provides a reliable endpoint for interacting with Ethereum Networks (viz. Mainnet, Ropsten, Rinkeby...). This solution works perfectly with Infura, try it and let me know if it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Hope this link below will help you:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html

you can read the whole documentation for better understanding.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Kishore, actually i have followed this guide. I can use the other APIs, except the "deploy" one.